# No me inserta los datos en la base de datos y no me muestra error (PHP)

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios, tablas

Tengo un formulario bastante sencillito y estoy intentando enviar los datos proporcionando por el usuario a una tabla llamada **contact** hasta ahora todo bien.
El problema radica cuando envió los datos ya que estos no se están insertando en la tabla como debería pero tampoco me esta mostrando un error y eso me deja sin opciones ya que no se donde se sucede el problema.

```
// Si no hay errores, registramos al usuario
    if(count($errors) === 0){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contact (id_contact, name_c, surname_c, email_c, message_c, browser_contact, ip_contact, create_at_contact) VALUES(
            null, :name, :surname, :email_c, :text, :browser, :ip, NOW())'
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':name' => $name,
            ':surname' => $surname,
            ':email_c' => $email_c,
            ':text' => $text,
            ':browser' => $browser,
            ':ip' => $ip
        ));

        $success = "$name, tu mensaje fue enviado con &eacute;xito!";

    }
```

Aquí básicamente lo que estoy diciendo es que si no hay errores que me inserte los datos en la tabla **contact** y que luego me envié un mensaje de éxito y me lo imprima por pantalla. Y efectivamente me imprime el mensaje de éxito pero no me inserta los datos en la tabla.[image: Mensaje de éxito mostrado por pantalla]

Aquí pueden ver que no me esta llegando nada a la base de datos y también pueden ver los nombres de los campos y hasta donde yo he pido revisar los nombres de los campos están correctamente escritos con los que están en el código PHP
[image: base de datos]

Comment: ¿Qué se muestra si pones después de `$conexion->execute(...);` `print_r($conexion->errorInfo());`?

Comment: Me muestra esto por pantalla: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: Verifica el nombre de la BDD con `INSERT INTO thecanario.contact ...`

Comment: Nuevamente no sucede nada, no aparecen los errores ni nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal parece tienes un error en tu sentencia de **SQL**. haciendo una comparación con la imagen de la tabla **contact** de la base de datos he notado que entre todas las columnas tienes una llamada `create_at_contact` pero en tu sentencia de **SQL** escribiste mal el nombre de esta y pusiste `crate_at_contact`.

Prueba colocando bien el nombre y eso solucionara tu error.

Comment: caja al contacto XD buen ojo

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo no soy tan experimentado, pero tu codigo por lo visto esta bien, podrias intentar sin la condicional de error, y otro punto seria que si tu tabla tiene el id autoincrementable, intenta sin pasarle null ni especificar id_contact, por que deberia de insertarse automaticamente,saludos amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Podés cambiar la variable "display_errors" de php.ini con `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` para que muestre los errores en el navegador.

O ver los logs en `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (o en donde corresponda en tu sistema operativo). Yo uso Ubuntu y pongo este comando en la terminal para que me vaya mostrando los errores:

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep php:error`
(con la opción -f va leyendo las actualizaciones del archivo)

En Windows 10 creo que sería este archivo:  `'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs'`

Y con Xampp debe ser algo así: `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Podés buscar la ubicación del archivo usando `phpinfo();` y buscando `APACHE_LOG_DIR`.

Answer (score 0):

No sé lo que sea `$errors` en tu contexto:

```
if(count($errors) === 0){
```

Lo cierto es que eso no sirve para controlar los errores que podrían ocurrir a posteriori, **preparando y ejecutando la consulta**. Haciendo ambas cosas podrían ocurrir errores (de sintaxis, de clave duplicada, etc) y deberías controlarlos.

Si quieres un código controlado, podrías hacer algo así. Aquí usamos un array `$msg` donde iremos poniendo una clave `success` o `error` según lo que ocurra. Y el contenido de esas claves será un mensaje descriptivo. En el caso de los errores he usado `errorInfo()` para depurar. En producción conviene cambiarlo por mensajes personalizados, pues no conviene mostrar al cliente mensajes de error internos del manejador o de la API.

```
<?php

$msg=array();
if(count($errors) === 0){
    $sql='INSERT INTO contact (id_contact, name_c, surname_c, email_c, message_c, browser_contact, ip_contact, create_at_contact) VALUES(
        null, :name, :surname, :email_c, :text, :browser, :ip, NOW())';
    if($stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql)) {
      $mParams=array(
          ':name' => $name,
          ':surname' => $surname,
          ':email_c' => $email_c,
          ':text' => $text,
          ':browser' => $browser,
          ':ip' => $ip
      );
      if ($stmt->execute($mParams)) {
        $msg['success'] = "$name, tu mensaje fue enviado con &eacute;xito!. Filas insertadas: ".$conexion->rowCount();
       } else {
         /*
            OJO: Aqui usamos $conexion->errorInfo()[2] sólo en depuración 
            considera cambiarlo luego por un mensaje personalizado ...
            También más abajo 
        */
         $msg['error']="Error en execute: ".$conexion->errorInfo()[2];
      }
    } else {
      $msg['error']="Error en prepare: ".$conexion->errorInfo()[2];  
    }
    # Verificamos el estado de $msg con un ternario
    $outPut= !empty($msg['success']) ? $msg['success'] : $msg['error'];
    # Imprimimos lo que haya ocurrido
    echo $outPut;
}

?>
```